# IOS : Should I delete my enterprise app before I submit the same app to App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise, bundle-identifier

I already deployed my app via Enterprise Program.
Now I plan to deploy my app into App Store.

My questions are:

- Should I change the `bundle ID`?
- Should I delete the app from `Enterprise` first before submitting to `App Store`?
- Is it possible to keep my `Enterprise app` while letting App Store team review my app?
- If I want to keep both of them, would there be any problem? Any solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, you will not be able to use same `bundle id` in another team.
Another team because one team can't be `enterprise` and `app store` at the same time.
So there is no problems to have two apps with different `bundle id`, I thinks it's obvious.
If it is especially necessary to use that `bundle id` in `app store` app, then you will need to delete it from `enterprise`.
So the easiest solution is just to change `bundle id`

Comment: I am going to change the bundle id. I just want to confirm. So it is okay to upload this exact same app (`Same UI`, `Same Functionality`) into `App Store` as long as it has different `bundle id` from the one in `Enterprise`? Is there any formal/informal document I can read about it?

Comment: Apple doesn't review `enterprise` apps, so they will not even know that there is exist `enterprise` app with the same ui and functionality.

Comment: Do you have any document to support that?

Comment: Sorry no. I assume that at https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#spam is talking only about `app store` <-> `app store` case.